# Same join command yields different output?

Tags: join

I ran the same commands on two different Ubuntu 14.04 x64 boxes, but got different results:

Ubuntu 1:

```
# join -1 2 -2 1 <(echo "st21 ppp0") <(echo "ppp0 9581720 213155315")
join: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory
```

Ubuntu 2:

```
# join -1 2 -2 1 <(echo "st21 ppp0") <(echo "ppp0 9581720 213155315")
ppp0 st21 9581720 213155315
```

So what's wrong with the first output?

Comment: Problem got fixed after a reboot of Ubuntu 1. But what happened?

Comment: It's hard to debug what happened. Maybe the keywords _process substitution_ and _anonymous pipe_ can help you with your google journey.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation is that `Ubuntu1` didn't have `/dev/fd` (normally a symlink to `/proc/self/fd`.  and normally created by `udev`).

`bash` needs `/dev/fd` for [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) to work.

After rebooting, `udev` did what it was supposed to do and created the symlink.

BTW, when you install `bash` on FreeBSD, it prompts you to add the following to `/etc/fstab` (not needed on linux, because it's handled by `udev` instead)

```
fdesc   /dev/fd     fdescfs     rw  0   0
```

Comment: So could it be that the /dev/fd had been mistakenly removed?

Comment: yes, that's definitely possible.